# Alternative condition for modular lattices

Tags: lattice-orders

A lattice is distributive if it holds the formula
\begin{equation}
a \vee (b \wedge c) = (a \vee b) \wedge (a \vee c).\tag{D}
\end{equation}

There are other equivalent conditions, and one is
\begin{equation}
(a \vee b = c \vee b \text{ and } a \wedge b = c \wedge b) \Rightarrow a = c.\tag{D'}
\end{equation}

A lattice is modular if it holds the formula
\begin{equation}
a \geq c \Rightarrow a \wedge (b \vee c) = (a \wedge b) \vee c.\tag{M}
\end{equation}

What could be a condition (M') for modular lattices, but similar to (D')?

Comment: (M) is more similar to (D') since they both involve an implication. Perhaps you want an (M') that is just a pure equation similar to (D)?

Comment: @0XLR thanks but I already knew an equation. I wanted something like in the answer provided. It was simpler than I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the condition $c \leq a$ to the antecedent of (D'), that is,
$$(a \vee b = c \vee b \;\text{and}\; a \wedge b = c \wedge b \;\text{and}\; c \leq a) \implies a = c.$$

Indeed, you can easily find elements in $N_5$ not satisfying the above condition.
But the condition above holds in every modular lattice:
\begin{align}
a
&= a \wedge (b \vee a) \tag{absorption}\\
&= a \wedge (b \vee c) \tag{hypothesis}\\
&= (a \wedge b) \vee c \tag{M}\\
&= (c \wedge b) \vee c \tag{hypothesis}\\
&= c.                  \tag{absorption}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I can’t upvote more for some hours. Then I will do it